# Beaglebone black and freeNas

Tags: freenas, beagleboard, beaglebone

Can the Beaglebone Black be used as a NAS controller using freeNAS software. I know it is doable on the Raspberry Pi. The specs of the beaglebone are superior to R.Pi so I am execpting even better performance. This is meant to be a fun poject but could also use it to actualy hst my NAS and ownCloud server. I will be using a hub to host two external HDD (USB 2.0) in RAID config

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've not used the Black myself but this will certainly be possible since you can run Linux on it.

There are lots of ways to deliver a simple NAS. The most common is simply to install SAMBA and create Windows style shared drives.

Don't expect the kind of performance delivered by a fully-fledged NAS such as my Synology 412+ though since that uses a more powerful processor, 1GB RAM, a dedicated RAID controller & twin 1Gb network cards. Still you might be able to get the kind of performance you could expect from a Pogo or similar.

Not sure that the cost of the Black vs the cost of one of the cheaper NAS devices makes much sense though as you are paying for features you wouldn't be using. OK if you already have one though.